# Make the stroke of the text much bigger

Tags: html, css, text, outline

Good day to all. So my problem is how to make the stroke much bolder?

I have this sample code

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700');

body{
background:black;
}
h1 {
  text-align:center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #FFFFFF, -1px -1px 0 #FFFFFF, 1px 1px 0 #FFFFFF, -1px 1px 0 #FFFFFF, 1px 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

```html
<h1>The quick brownfox jumps over the lazy dog</h1>
```

So how could I make the white line to be much wider like `3px`?

I've already try to change them all to `3px` but it have some small gaps.

**Edit**:

If any of you guys have an alternative solution that still displays the white line of the text, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: I think svg is the possible solution for my problem.. I'll try to look at it..

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into SVG solutions, here's a great tutorial that explains it all really well http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/text-element.html

```css
body{
    background:black;
    color : #fff
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="60">
    <text x="10" y="40"
        style="font-family: 'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif;
        font-size: 44px;
        stroke: #ffffff;
        stroke-width: 2px;
        fill: #000000;">
    THE QUICK BROWNFOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG
    </text>
</svg>
```

Below I've tweaked your code slightly - this version renders a bit neater - less gaps - however to get a really nice thick stroke SVG would be a more reliable solution.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700');

body{
background:black;
}
h1 {
  text-align:center;
  text-shadow:
 -1px -1px 0 #fff,
 1px -1px 0 #fff,
 -1px 1px 0 #fff,
 1px 1px 0 #fff;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

```html
<h1>The quick brownfox jumps over the lazy dog</h1>
```

Comment: you may consider adding an example with your SVG solution. A link to a solution isn't an anwser

Answer (score -1):

A possibility, if it is compatible with your target browser, is to use the 
[text-stroke](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke) property. Be careful as **it is not a standard feature**, so it might be unreliable. Unfortunately there does not seem to be a standard way to achieve what you want, except for a width of 1 px.

You could take the alternative route of creating the outlined text as an image to add to your page.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700');

body{
background:black;
}

h1 {
   text-align:center;
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
   -webkit-text-stroke-width: 3px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: #FFFFFF;
   text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

```html
<h1>The quick brownfox jumps over the lazy dog</h1>
```